# Strange label with TikZ-Feymann package and difficulty in math-mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, diagrams, labels, tikz-feynman

Starting from a recent answer

[image]

with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\newcommand{\virgola}{\smash{\raisebox{0.1ex}{,}}}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [boson,edge label'=\(p\virgola a\),charged boson] b
-- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5,edge label'=\(\scriptstyle q+\frac{p}{2}\)] c
-- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5, edge label'=\(\scriptstyle q-\frac{p}{2}\)] b,
c -- [boson,edge label'=\(p\virgola a\),charged boson] d,
};

\end{document}
```

I have encountered these difficulties:

> 1. I am not able to put the label of every fermion to outside of the graph. I read the manual and there is only the option of placing under boson, photon, etc.. I think that is exist only this option: `edge label'`;
> 2. Into the label can I put only symbols? For example I have created a comma "virgola" in math-mode. If I do not adopt this solution I get errors.

*What are the solutions?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `edge label'`, the `'` means "move label to the other side of the line", so use `edge label` instead of `edge label'`.

Regarding the comma, the problem is that the option list is a comma separated list, so if you have a comma in one of the entries you need to protect it with braces. In other words, use `foo={bar, baz}` instead of `foo=bar,baz`, otherwise the parser is confused by the comma. In your case, `edge label'={\(p, a\)}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [boson,edge label'={\(p, a\)},charged boson] b
-- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5,edge label=\(\scriptstyle q+\frac{p}{2}\)] c
-- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5, edge label=\(\scriptstyle q-\frac{p}{2}\)] b,
c -- [boson,edge label'={\(p,a\)},charged boson] d,
};

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I thinked that `edge label'` and `'edge label` to put a label up/down. I must read well the documentation. I often help me with the examples, because for me the English language, often, in the documentation is very hard.

Comment: @Sebastiano Think of it as left/right instead. With `edge label` the label is placed in the left side, if you look along the direction of the line, with `edge label'` it is placed on the right side.

Comment: Again thank you for your simple explanation. Why some documentations non are very simple? :-/